# Remove commas from JSON_EXTRACT in csv format, php

Tags: php, json, csv

When i am extracting the files from db in csv format after every name i am getting commas that i don't know from where they are apearing. Check the screenshot: [how the csv file looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cSOS.jpg)

This is the code:

```
function expired(){
  if(isset($_POST['download']))
       {

           $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
           $time = (time());
           $query = "select user_id, profile_value FROM #__user_metadata WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.expiry_date') > '$time'";
            $db->setQuery($query);

             $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

               header('Content-type: text/csv');
                ob_end_clean(); // is cleaning the space before the list

                 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=UserDatabase.csv');
                 ob_start();
                $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

             foreach ($rows as $row) {

                $user_id = json_decode($row->user_id);

                 $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
                $query = "select user_id, profile_value FROM #__user_metadata WHERE user_id = '$user_id'" ;
                $db->setQuery($query);

                $rows = $db->loadObjectList();


                foreach ($rows as $row) {

                $profile_value = json_decode($row->profile_value);


                $first_name=$profile_value->first_name;

                $last_name=$profile_value->last_name;
                $email =$profile_value->email;

                $users = array($first_name . " " . $last_name, $email);
               fputcsv($output, $users, ',') ;

                   }

        }
         fclose($output);
            ob_end_flush();
            exit(0);

}

}
```

looks like the json_extract is taking all the users that are in db but is not displaying them, just an empty slot separated by the coma and the problem is not comming from that line:

```
fputcsv($output, $users, ',') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change all the code in order to take them off. This is the solution:
Maybe you will find for you something helpfull. The problem was that in variable $users i a had double arrays.

```
   $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $app = JFactory::getApplication(); //
     $user_type= $app->input->getString('user_type');


       switch($user_type){

        case  'Export expired danish users':

         $query = "select user_id, profile_value FROM #__user_metadata WHERE profile_key = 'profile20.subscription_shared' AND JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.expiry_date') > '$time'";
               $rows = $db->loadObjectList();




         break;

         case 'foreign':
            $query = "select user_id, profile_value FROM #__user_metadata WHERE profile_key = 'profile20.subscription_shared' AND JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.expiry_date') > '$time'";
               $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
               break;
             default:

           $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
          $query = "select user_id, profile_value FROM #__user_metadata WHERE profile_key = 'profile20.subscription_shared' AND JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.expiry_date') > '$time'";
            $db->setQuery($query);

            break;

   }

        header('Content-type: text/csv');
        ob_end_clean(); // is cleaning the space before the list

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=UsersWithExpiredDate.csv');
        ob_start();
        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

        foreach ($rows as $row) {

            $user_id = $row->user_id;

             $query = "SELECT JSON_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.email')) AS email, JSON_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.first_name')) AS first_name, JSON_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(profile_value, '$.last_name')) AS last_name FROM nagwm_user_metadata WHERE user_id = '$user_id ' AND profile_key = 'profile20.profile_data'";

            $db->setQuery($query);

            $rows = $db->loadRow();

            $first_name=$rows[1];


            $last_name=$rows[2];
            $email =$rows[0];

            $users = array($first_name . " " . $last_name, $email); 
            fputcsv($output, $users) ;  

        }
            fclose($output);
            ob_end_flush();
            exit(0);
```